# How to bind a return from an AJAX call to an Angular $scope variable

Tags: angularjs, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC application with an Angular front-end. I. Successfully call the Angular `GetData()` function on page load and I've traced to confirm that Home/DataRefresh is returning data in the correct format.

However when I use data to populate a table in the view nothings shows up, no errors, the calls all complete, the table is just empty.

I have a suspicion that it has something to do with how you have to access the Angular $scope within a non-angular function but I'm too new to angularjs to know for sure. I've read through all the documentation I could find to no avail.

EDIT: Per suggestion here's the $http call and the Angular it's contained in.

```
app.controller("processModel", function ($scope) {
    $scope.sortType = 'SchedWk';
    $scope.sortReverse = false;

    $scope.GetData = function() {
        $scope.LoadData();
    };

    $scope.LoadData = function() {
        //$.ajax({
        //    type: "GET",
        //    url: 'Home/DataRefresh',
        //    dataType: "json",
        //    success: function (data) {
        //      $scope.data = data;
        //    }, 
        //    error: function (a, b, c) {
        //        alert("The jqXHR object:  " + a + " Error Type:  " + b + " Error Description:  " + c);
        //    }
        //});
        $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: '/Home/DataRefresh'
        }).then(function success(data) {
            $scope.data = data;
        }, function error(errResponse) {
            alert("y u break it tho");
        });
    };  
});
```

Comment: Were you able to get it working?

Comment: Swapping from $.ajax to $http and accessing the data via response.data was the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike jQuery AJAX, the $http service returns a `response` object, of which  `data` is attached as a property of that object:

```
$http({
    method: "GET",
    url: '/Home/DataRefresh'
}).then(function success( ̶d̶a̶t̶a̶ response) {
    ̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶d̶a̶t̶a̶ ̶=̶ ̶d̶a̶t̶a̶;̶
    $scope.data = response.data;
}, function error(errResponse) {
    alert("y u break it tho");
});
```

From the Docs:

> ### `$http` Returns
>
> A [Promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) that will be resolved (request success) or rejected (request failure) with a response object.
>
> The response object has these properties:
>
> - **data** – `{string|Object}` – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
> - **status** – `{number}` – HTTP status code of the response.
> - **headers** – `{function([headerName])}` – Header getter function.
> - **config** – `{Object}` – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
> - **statusText** – `{string}` – HTTP status text of the response.
> - **xhrStatus** – `{string}` – Status of the XMLHttpRequest (`complete`, `error`, `timeout` or `abort`).
>
> [-— AngularJS $http Service API Reference - Returns](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#$http-returns).

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question. Even in its current state the "data" will still bind to the $scope, but will just be nested down one level like this {"data": [actual response data]}. He was reporting that there was nothing bound to his $scope at all.

Comment: @dkaramazov that was because I was using $.ajax before and it wasn't saving to scope at all and so data was just empty.

This answer, plus the swap from $.ajax to $http fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to call `$scope.apply()` in the handler after setting the data only the scope because that handler after the ajax call is happening outside of Angular. If you used Angular's `$http` service instead of `$.ajax`, you wouldn't need to handle that manually.

Comment: Are there any benefits to using AJAX over Angular's built in method or vice versa? Also where would I need to place the call to $scope.apply() right after I assign data to $scope.data or after the ajax call?

Comment: In general, you should stick with using Angular's built in capabilities rather than rely on other libraries like jQuery. This issue is a good example why.

Comment: I've updated the OP to show the $http code I'm currently trying. DataRefresh wasn't getting hit at all anymore and then I noticed I was getting a Java Runtime error " '$http' is undefined ".   Do I need to install a separate package or something to get access to that function?

Comment: You need to inject it into your controller

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject the $http service first:

```
app.controller("processModel", function($scope, $http) { 
    $scope.sortType = 'SchedWk'; 
    $scope.sortReverse = false; 
    $scope.GetData = function() { 
        $scope.LoadData(); 
    }; 
    $scope.LoadData = function() { 
       $http({ 
            method: "GET", 
            url: '/HomeDataRefresh' 
       }).then(function success(data) { 
            $scope.data = data; 
       }, function error(errResponse) { 
            alert("y u break it tho");
       }); 
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You lost the reference to $scope in your AJAX call because it is nested into several JavaScript Functions. When using a JQuery AJAX call you can force AngularJS to pick it up by calling $scope.$apply() which will run the digest loop again.

You really should be using $http or $q to take advantage of Promises in JavaScript. They are very powerful and simplify the use of asynchronous operations in JavaScript.

This link should get you up and running quickly:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

To include $http in your controller you'll need to inject it as in my example.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('postController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.data = 'empty';
    $scope.runAJAX = function(){
  $http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then(function(response){
            $scope.data = response.data;
        }).catch(function(error){
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="postController">
    <div>
        {{data}}
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" value="run AJAX" ng-click="runAJAX()"/>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My answer was in reference to the original state of the question which just had an AJAX call, no $http. Was my explanation of the AJAX call wrong?

Comment: No. Unfortunate that OP changed code in the question

Comment: What should I do with my answer? I don't want to get down voted again.

Comment: Maye just add a mention about "when using using `$.ajax`" since it is outside angular context

Comment: Done. I appreciate you clarifying that.